# PDFsharp - Table Of Contents - C#

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, tableofcontents

I'm using PDFsharp to create a PDF file, I'm now about to generate a Table Of Contents. How can I set the dot between the text dynamically?

I'm using XRect and a XGraphics Object to draw the String.

And set the Link with AddDocumentLink()
e.g:

```
Text..................... 1

Text2.................... 2

Chapter4 ................ 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DrawString` to draw the dots. You can use `MeasureString` to find out how many dots will fit.

PDFsharp was created for use with MigraDoc. And MigraDoc makes the creation of a ToC quite simple:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloMigraDoc-sample.ashx
I mention this just in case that switching to a related library is an option.

Comment: I think i would use Migradoc.  can i create or edit certains pages of the Document with PDFSharp and another with MigraDoc? Thanks

Comment: It's relatively easy to create all pages using MigraDoc, but add some contents using PDFsharp. It is simple to create some PDF pages using PDFsharp and add them to a MigraDoc document. Long story short: there are many ways, depending on your needs and requirements.